# Make only part of a resources string a link in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization

My goal is to have a string with a link that opens a new window. The catch is that the string has to be localizable.

In order for our localization tool to be able to recognize the strings, it has to be defined like this:

```
<sys:String x:Uid="testString" x:Key="testString">click here for a good time</sys:String>
```

The string would then be referenced like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource testString}"/>
```

I need the word "here" to be a link that opens another window. The other words should do nothing when clicked on.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason these strings can't be split up?  You are already assuming in your question that 'here' translates to the place they should click.

```
<sys:String x:Uid="prefix" x:Key="testString">click</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Uid="caption" x:Key="testString">here</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Uid="suffix" x:Key="testString">for a good time</sys:String>

<StackPanel>
   <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource prefix}" />
   <Button Command={StaticResource someCommand}>
      <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource caption}" />
   </Button>
   <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource suffix}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this even possible?

Not without splitting up the `string` into words somehow and write some code. You need to define the actual link somewhere.

You could for example handle the `Loaded` event for the `TextBlock` and populate its `Inline` property.

Here is an example that should give you the idea.

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource testString}" Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded"/>
```

---

```
private void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const string linkText = "here";
    TextBlock txt = sender as TextBlock;
    string[] words = txt.Text.Split(' ');
    if (words.Contains(linkText))
    {
        txt.Text = string.Empty;
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (word == linkText)
            {
                var link = new Hyperlink(new Run(linkText + " "));
                link.Click += (ss, ee) =>
                {
                    //do something when the link is clicked on
                };
                txt.Inlines.Add(link);
            }
            else
            {
                txt.Inlines.Add(word + " ");
            }
        }
        txt.Text.TrimEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.

The string can't be split up because "click here for a good time" could be translated differently as a whole sentence than sticking together the already translated words.

Comment: So where you define that that the word "here" is to be clickable...?